# Understanding bind mapping to switch between emacs and vi modes

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters, fzf

### tl;dr

If I execute the following in `bash`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> seems to have no effect

```bash
bind -m vi-command '"\C-z": emacs-editing-mode'
bind -m vi-insert '"\C-z": emacs-editing-mode'
bind -m emacs-standard '"\C-z": vi-editing-mode'
```

whereas something dumb like this just works

```bash
bind -m vi-insert '"h": "ciaooooo"'
```

### The origin of this question

It's not that I want to use those mappings, as I'm happy with `vi-editing-mode` all the time, but I'd like to understand the behavior I observe, mostly because I'm interested in how [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)'s [`key-bindings.bash`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash) works.

`key-bindings.bash` defines a bunch of functions, such as [`__fzf_select__`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/2c6a73546ddefe7c1c1c01e4282e1df06bfe82e8/shell/key-bindings.bash#L16), [`__fzf_cd__`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/2c6a73546ddefe7c1c1c01e4282e1df06bfe82e8/shell/key-bindings.bash#L43) and others, and then binds them in various ways to keys.

Now, assuming [a recent enough `bash`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/2c6a73546ddefe7c1c1c01e4282e1df06bfe82e8/shell/key-bindings.bash#L85), the binds go like so:

```bash
# Required to refresh the prompt after fzf
bind -m emacs-standard '"\er": redraw-current-line'

bind -m vi-command '"\C-z": emacs-editing-mode'
bind -m vi-insert '"\C-z": emacs-editing-mode'
bind -m emacs-standard '"\C-z": vi-editing-mode'

#if (( BASH_VERSINFO[0] < 4 )); then
# older versions of the commands in the else branch
#else
  # CTRL-T - Paste the selected file path into the command line
  bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-t": fzf-file-widget'
  bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-t": fzf-file-widget'
  bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-t": fzf-file-widget'

  # CTRL-R - Paste the selected command from history into the command line
  bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
  bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
  bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
#fi

# ALT-C - cd into the selected directory
bind -m emacs-standard '"\ec": " \C-b\C-k \C-u`__fzf_cd__`\e\C-e\er\C-m\C-y\C-h\e \C-y\ey\C-x\C-x\C-d"'
bind -m vi-command '"\ec": "\C-z\ec\C-z"'
bind -m vi-insert '"\ec": "\C-z\ec\C-z"'
```

Here, as far as `__fzf_history__` and `fzf-file-widget` are concerned, the same mapping is executed on the 3 keymaps `emacs-standard`, `vi-command`, and `vi-insert`. So far so good.

However, for `__fzf_cd__` the story is different:

- only `bind -m emacs-standard` references it, inside a mad sequence of, I believe, emacs-specific keystrokes,
- whereas `bind -m vi-command`/`vi-insert` seem to leverage the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> mapping (top-ish of the snippet above) for switching between `emacs-editing-mode` and `vi-editing-mode`, thus applying the logic

  1. go to `emacs-editing-mode` mode
  2. hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
  3. go back to `vi-editing-mode` mode

I'm relatively sure the above analsys is correct, mostly.

But the mappings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> are defined in the same scope as those for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, which make use of the former; but the latter work whereas the former don't.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect what's happening is that when trying it out manually the "\C-z" is getting caught by the terminal itself as the "suspend" character.

Hence the `readline` built into `bash` never actually sees that character, and hence never performs the relevant action.
When that "\C-z" is part of a mapping it's not coming through the terminal and hence not intercepted.

I'd guess this is why fzf chose to use that particular key for their "internal" switching.

In order to check this you could open a new terminal and run `stty -a`.  In that output I'd expect you'll see `susp = ^Z;` to confirm that the C-z character is indeed what the terminal will be looking for.

Then in that same terminal you could run `stty susp ^X` to make the suspend character `^X` instead of `^Z` before testing the `C-z` mapping you have defined to switch to `emacs-editing-mode`, if I'm right your keybindings should have changed.

Bullet points to be clear:

- `bind -m vi-insert '"\C-z": emacs-editing-mode'`
- `stty -a` (just to view).
- `stty susp ^X`
- Press `C-z` and see if keybindings have changed.

Comment: Excelent answer and welcome to this site!